# Load pivot tables with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, automated-tests, apache-poi, pivot-table

I'm trying to use Apache POI to validate an recently dowloaded excel.
The flow is basically:

1. Open a web app
2. Download an excel file from this web app
3. Imediatally open this file using Apache POI
4. Validate values, formulas, etc... in all sheets of this excel

The problem is that when I try to check the cells, they cannot be read, they are being considered null.
These cells are inside pivot tables and they are probably being loaded when excel file is open manually, I think in this way because if I simply open the excel and save without doing anything, the cells that were before considered null, can be read normally.
Does anyone know how can I do this "initial load" for these pivot tables?
I tried to open, save, close and open again the excel using Apache, but I didn't work.
Once this should be a full automated flow the step of opening the excel and saving it manually is discarted for me.

Please let me know if you guys get any doubts on that.

Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid the initial file was not created by `Excel` but using `apache poi` or a similar software which only creates pivot table definitions without rendering the pivot tables in the sheet. Then the sheet data is empty until `Excel` opens the file and renders the pivot table. `Apache poi` will not do this, as you observed already. So you are lost here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AxelRichter, do you know any other way or work around to do that?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. As said, `Excel` renders the pivot table to the sheet. And `LibreOffice` or `OpenOffice` `Calc` also does. So if a program interacts with `Excel` or `LibreOffice` or `OpenOffice` to open the file and resave, then the sheet will have data of the pivot table after that. But that is exactly not what `apache poi` is for. `Apache poi` does not interact with `Excel`. It not needs any `Excel` application to work. I don't know whether `Aspose` renders pivot tables or not.